# convert a message of a txt file lower case to upper case?something like that $file:toUpper() but nothing

Tags: spring, type-conversion, apache-camel, case, message

[convert a lower case message txt to an upper case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPkFy.png)

How to convert a lower case message txt to an upper case? Using transform operator?

Comment: I tried ${in.body.toUpper()} but its does nothing...

Comment: `${bodyAs(String).toUpperCase()}`